# how to increase spacing between xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar plot but the ticks on x axis are very close to each other and I would like to increase spacing between xticks. Below are the codes I used for plotting.

```
x = np.arange(len(df1['Region']))
plt.bar(x-0.5, 'drunk_drv16', data = df1, label = "Year 2016", width = 0.5)
plt.bar(x, 'drunk_drv17', data = df1, label = "Year 2017", width = 0.5)
plt.bar(x+0.5, 'drunk_drv18', data = df1, label = "Year 2018", width = 0.5)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90, fontsize = 8)
plt.xticks(x, df1['Region'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot image]

Please suggest some method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of ticks in x axis being close are, is because your figure size is small. You could increase the figure size, by adding this just before the first command using plt

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18,12))  ## width, height
```

You can play with these numbers depending on how you want the graph to be positioned